# AES process candidates implementations and usages

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher

There were fifteen candidates in the AES selection and I suppose that Rijndael wasn't the single good algorithm. I know that Camellia is an evolution of E2 candidate and can be used as symmetric cryptographic routines in TLS. Which others ex-candidates have today a "serious" implementation and a real usage ?

Comment: Twofish, Serpent

Answer (score 6):

Well, not all of the AES-candidates have been considered good. In fact one of them even got broken at the presentation (within 20min!).

I'll list any (non-author) occurence of algoriths I'm aware of. Note: This list doesn't claim to be complete and may be extended by other people.

Now for a list of algorithms, for which I know there're an option

- SAFER, well it's predecessor, SAFER-K and SAFER-SK are available at least in the [Crypto++ library](http://cryptopp.com)
- CAST-256, available in the [Crypto++ library](http://cryptopp.com)
- MARS, finalist, available in the [Crypto++ library](http://cryptopp.com), because of the finalist status it may be an option in other programs
- RC6, finalist, available in the [Crypto++ library](http://cryptopp.com), available in [Jetico's encryption tool](http://www.jetico.com/products/personal-privacy/bestcrypt-volume-encryption/), may be an option in other places as well as it's simpler than MARS and also has finalist status, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC6) it was used pre-AES by the NSA. Furthermore usage of this algorithm can be costly as [RSA Labratories seem to hold patents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC6#Licensing) on it, as RC6 didn't win the AES-competition.
- Serpent, finalist, 2nd place of the AES process, back then it was believed to be the most secure available candidate, adopted in [Crypto++](http://cryptopp.com) and available in [Jetico's tools](http://www.jetico.com/products/personal-privacy/bestcrypt-volume-encryption/) and in TrueCrypt and it's derivatives (e.g. CipherShed and VeraCrypt).
- Twofish, finalist, 3rd place of the AES process, back then it was approximiately as fast as Rijndael but it was believed to be more secure, adopted in [Crypto++](http://cryptopp.com), TrueCrypt, [by Jetico](http://www.jetico.com/products/personal-privacy/bestcrypt-volume-encryption/) and in [KeePass](http://keepass.info) (1.x, 2.x as plug-in), and is part of the OpenPGP standard.

Comment: Isn't RC6 patented?

Comment: @poncho it looks like it actually is and RSA would only allowed "free-use" in case of RC6 being the winner of AES.... I'll update the answer accordingly.